# How can I pass a class as data to Laravel's 5 Queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-5.6

So I have this line:

```
Queue::pushOn(config('notification.queue_type_log'), config('notification.job'), new LogDelivery($notification) );
```

Basically I want to push the object LogDelivery as data to my queuing job class.

I'm using RabbitMq and when querying for the message in my queue, in the admin panel of RabbitMq,it only gets the job namespace but not the data.

I have to mention that my class is not a Command, just a regular class that implements:

```
class **LogDelivery** extends **AbstractDelivery** implements **ShouldBeQueued**
```

Comment: What does `$notification` contain? Could you pass that variable to the queue and do `new LogDelivery` in the queue processor class?

Comment: @ceejayoz: $notification is an object!